# Removing some ID from a large text file based on two another text files

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a large text file (file A) as below:

```
ID1 ID2 0.2
ID3 ID6 0.4
ID4 ID2 0.6
ID5 ID8 0.8
ID7 ID14    0.4
ID3 ID9 0.6 
ID8 ID10 0.8
```

I have also two another text files (B and C), which file B is like below:

```
ID1
ID2
ID3
ID4
ID5
ID6
ID7
```

and file C is like:

```
ID8
ID9
ID10
ID11
ID12
ID13
ID14
```

I would like to keep just those row of the file A that the related contents of two first columns belong to both file B and file C. For example, I want just these rows from file A:

```
ID10 ID3    0.8
ID7 ID14    0.4
ID3 ID9 0.6
```

Because the ID 10 and ID3 belonged to both two files of B and C, and so on. Could you please kindly let me know how to obtain such an output?

Many thanks

Comment: What about `ID5 ID8 0.8`? And `ID10 ID3    0.8` does not occur in the data.

Answer (score 1):

Simply `grep` the `A` file for strings occurring in the `B` file, and then `grep` the result of that for strings occurring in the `C` file.

```
$ ( grep -wF -f fileB | grep -wF -f fileC ) <fileA
ID5 ID8 0.8
ID7 ID14    0.4
ID3 ID9 0.6
```

The options used with `grep` are

- `-w` to only ever match whole words (this is a commonly available, but non-standard option). We use this option to not match `ID10` when grepping for `ID1`.
- `-F` to interpret the patterns as strings, not as regular expressions.
- `-f` to read the patterns to match with from a separate file.

Comment: Many thanks for your response.

Comment: @Mary You may want to look at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, and also take the
tour: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour (you'll receive a badge when
you've done so).